# C Basic scanf not working

Tags: c, int

```
int g1,g2,g3,g4;
scanf("%d %d %d %d", &g1, &g2, &g3, &g4);
g[0] = g1;
g[1] = g2;
g[2] = g3;
g[4] = g4;
```

For whatever reason g[4] is not registered. I'm not exactly sure what the problem is, anyone have any input?

Comment: What's the input? What is scanf returning?

Comment: Any chance that you meant `g[3]` and not `g[4]`?

Comment: Derp. It's a monday morning, sorry guys. This was a very stupid question.

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant to set `g[3] = g4` instead of `g[4] = g4`. If your array is size 4 then the last element will be at index **3**.

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure the array "g" is declared and it is of size 5. This will allocate memory that can be accessed by array index 0,1,2,3 and 4. According to the below code, g[3] is never used but has allocated memory.

Assuming you are using integer array, below is the syntax that works fine:

```
    int g[5];
    int g1,g2,g3,g4l;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &g1, &g2, &g3, &g4);
    g[0] = g1;
    g[1] = g2;
    g[2] = g3;
    g[4] = g4;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
int g1,g2,g3,g4,g[4];
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &g1, &g2, &g3, &g4);
        g[0] = g1;
        g[1] = g2;
        g[2] = g3;
        g[3] = g4;
printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d",g[0],g[1],g[2],g[3]);
return 0;
        }
```